# iOS Animation - View should be outside the superview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, animation

I have created a UIBezierPath object that I wish to move around the superview based on values received from the Accelerometer. I was trying to play around with UIView Animations and I am not quite sure I understand this code particularly well.

The code for the UIBezierPath object is below:

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: pathCenter, radius: pathRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*M_PI), clockwise: true)
    UIColor.blueColor().setFill()
    UIColor.greenColor().setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = 2.0
    path.fill()
    path.stroke()
}
```

In the ViewController I perform the animation using the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        //self.ballView.center.x += self.view.frame.width
    }
    print(self.ballView.center.x)
    print(self.view.frame.width)
}
```

The confusion I am facing is about the dimensions of the ballView and superview (the ViewController's view)

This line `self.ballView.center.x` returns 187.5 and `self.view.frame.width` returns 375.0, so if I perform the commented line of code, `self.ballView.center.x += self.view.frame.width` shouldn't the ballView's `center.x` value be 555.75 and therefore outside the ViewControllers view. Instead the ballView is positioned at the center of the `self.view`. Please let me know what exactly is going on.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong. I'm not sure why that is. Is the ballView's superview the ViewController's view? Otherwise try putting the animation in the `viewDidAppear` method instead.

Comment: Yes, the ballView's superview is the ViewController's view

Comment: Is the issue that the ballView is not actually moving and animating? Or that the value of the centre isn't what you expect it to be when you print?

Comment: In the viewDidAppear the ballView moves outside the ViewControllers view to the right. I expected that the ballView would move outside the superview since 187.5+375 is greater than the superviews frame.width property which happens to be 375.0. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, that all makes sense. So what exactly is your issue?

Comment: How come when I comment out the line in the UIView.animateWithDuration method, the ballView is still in the center? Shouldn't it be outside the superview (to the right)?

Comment: When it's commented out, then the ballView centre value will not change at all during runtime. Therefore it will stay where it originally was. I'm assuming that is the centre of the screen.

Comment: No no, i commented it out only for SO purposes. If it is uncommented, the ballView moves from left to the center of the screen which is not what i expected. is there an email address i can send u the xcode project on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the animation into a `viewDidAppear` method instead. Like so:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.ballView.center.x += self.view.frame.width
    }
}
```